# How to put electrical wires and boxes in insulated (but not drywalled) walls?

Tags: electrical, insulation, basement

I have a basement, with concrete exterior walls which are framed with wood studs, and pink fiberglass insulation between them, all covered with a vapor barrier. I'm going to finish the basement, and need to add electrical receptacles to these walls.

I've read several conflicting advises about how to proceed in this situation: wires on top of insulation, wires behind, or buried inside it, just cut the insulation, or remove it altogether, etc., etc... So I'd like to know what is the best way to proceed in this situation? I'd like to make it right, but with the least amount of effort.

Comment: Bring the wires down the stud staple to the stud within 12" of the box, make sure your boxes are 1/2" in front of the stud so they will be flush when the Sheetrock is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the correct way to do it is to remove the insulation, run the wires in the middle of the stud cavity, then re-insert the insulation (splitting it in half top-to bottom where needed to put it around wires in the middle. The fix the vapor barrier as needed.